# I want to randomly change Google Marker position through loop or something

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps-markers

I'm new with **Google API**, I want to change Google Marker position automatically on google map and it's auto-change position on map after five seconds. I didn't have DB for latitude and longitude.
I mean to say marker change its position randomly on the map.

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: I mean to say marker change its position randomly on the map after some 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** You can achieve this using vanilla Javascript.

Since you do not have a database, you could use an array of [LatLng class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates) to specify the coordinates that you want to be displayed:

```
  //an array of geographical coordinates
  var locations = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(6.528166, 20.439864), //somewhere in Africa
      new google.maps.LatLng(34.494890, 103.854720), //somewhere in China
      new google.maps.LatLng(51.802090, 7.771800), // somewhere in Germany
      new google.maps.LatLng(46.153450, -101.948783), // somewhere in US
      new google.maps.LatLng(-11.495951, -49.266451), // somewhere in Brazil
      new google.maps.LatLng(-80.287421, 23.599101) // somewhere in Antartica
  ];
```

After that, you can use the `setInterval()` function which will contain the code that randomizes the items on the array of geographical coordinates and changes the map and marker's position.

```
// set interval that will repeat every after 5 seconds
setInterval(function() {

    // pick random coordinates from the locations array
    var randomLocation = locations[Math.floor(Math.random() * locations.length)];

    // change the map center
    map.setCenter(randomLocation);

    // change the marker position
    marker.setPosition(randomLocation);
}, 5000);
```

Please find the working sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ujbn1o5f/).

I hope this helps!